# add and remove view from framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm working on one demo in which I'm using `FrameLayout` on which dynamically adding `XML` named "frame_layout_data " containing views like `ImageView`, `EditText`which I can move in `FrameLayout` anywhere using `onTouchListener`. What I want to do is to remove those Views from `FrameLayout` and add them again on button click, just like resetting them.
I tried

```
framelayout.removeAllView();
```

Which removes view from `FrameLayout`. But when I add the next line,

```
framelayout.addView(framelayoutcontaints);
```

the moved view does not get removed and even new view does not get added.. :(
I also tried Visibility option but it doesn't worked..

Comment: `addView(view)`. why do you have `R.id.framelayoutcontaint` id is a integer value

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry I corrected it.. Its `framelayout.addView(framelayoutcontaints);` not`framelayout.addView(R.idframelayoutcontaints);`

Comment: ok. what is `framelayoutcontaints`?. if its a view can add view as a child to framelayout.

Comment: Its `View framelayoutcontaints= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout_data ,container, false);`

Comment: code looks alright. making views invisible and visible should also work

Comment: Then what is the problem?? when I remove view they get remove using `framelayout.removeAllView();`

Comment: I tried that also but views not get `INVISIBLE `..

Comment: @Raghunandan should I keep some time inrevalt between remove and add..??

Comment: @Aksh no, there is no such need, post your code

Comment: @pskink I just used Dialog for reset button contain Yes, No..`  dialogyesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
  f.removeView(framelayoutview);
  if(f.getChildAt(0)==null){
   f.addView(framelayoutview);
  }
 dialog.dismiss();
 }
 }` on first time yes click View get remove and on second time yes clicked view get added ?? I want on them at single time